# Regex for replacing letters next to numbers uppercase

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this regex `(\w+)` replace with `\u$0`

This makes first letter caps for example: `james1` to `James1`.

But I need a regex to make the first letter caps of each word when it starts with a number for example

```
12james

1azz4ds

1995brandon


666metal
```

to

```
12James

1Azz4ds

1995Brandon


666Metal
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your current regex will capitalize any word whether it ends in a number or not. Unclear whether you were aware of that. For your main problem, you could change `(\d+)(regex-describing-word-that-doesn't-start-with-a-digit)` to `$0\u$1`

Comment: Do words contain any characters besides letters and digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match a word boundary `\b`, match 1+ digits `\d+` and then forget what is matched using `\K`. Then match a single lowercase a-z:

```
\b\d+\K[a-z]
```

Replace with:

```
\u$0
```

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vz6pzy/1)

If there can be not a non whitespace before the digits, instead of using `\b` you might also use:

```
(?<!\S)\d+\K[a-z]
```

See another [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vz6pzy/2)

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can also collect the digits, then letters maybe both upper or lowercase, and replace it:

```
[0-9]+([A-Za-z])
```

[image]

We will be adding a start char to capture only those letters that we wish to replace:

```
^[0-9]+([A-Za-z])
```

or:

```
^([0-9]+)([A-Za-z])
```

and for this expression our replacement would look like to something similar to:

```
$1\u$2
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vl0NsU/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]